# Web 8 Install Step Configuring the maximum size of all uploads to Content Manager

Tags: web8, installation

The [Configuring the maximum size of all uploads to Content Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-34F150BF-EA1A-400C-A432-0A0D2033D6BD) page in the SDL Web 8.5 online documentation suggests the following:

> On your Content Manager server,
>
> 1. Open **%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config** for editing.
> 2. Find the `binding` element with its name attribute set to the value `streamUpload_basicHttp`.
> 3. Change one or both of the following values: ...

However, in my vanilla SDL Web 8.5 install, I cannot find a `binding` element with the `name` attribute of `streamUpload_basicHttp`.

Here is an excerpt of my **TcmServiceHost.exe.config** file:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="CoreService_netTcpBinding" ...>...</binding>
    <binding name="StreamDownload_netTcpBinding" .../>
    <binding name="StreamUpload_netTcpBinding" .../>
    <binding name="EclService_netTcpBinding" .../>...</binding>
    <binding name="TmService_netTcpBinding" .../>...</binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CoreService_netFederationTcpBinding">
      ...
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Q1. Is `StreamUpload_netTcpBinding` a default binding?

Q2. Where do we need to specify the bindings to be used while installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received the below response from SDL Support.

An out of the box default configuration has only "streamUpload_netTcpBinding"., if you need any other binding, we will need to configure manually.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in answer to Q2, **if** you do need to add a `binding` element with the `name` attribute of `streamUpload_netTcpBinding`, then this should be nested inside of a `<basicHttpBinding>` element.

For example:

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        ...
      </netTcpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        ...
      </customBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamDownload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="Basic" -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamUpload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Mtom" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```